# making a list of lists from a file

Tags: python, list, function

I want to make a function that receives a file of several lines, for example:

```
A B 1
C D 2
E F 3
```

and returns a list of lists like this: [['A', 'B', '1'], ['C', 'D', '2'], ['E', 'F', '3']]

This is the code I tried:

```
def f(filename: str) -> list:
    with open(filename,'r') as file:
        content=file.readlines()
        file.close()
        for i in range(len(content)):
            l=[list(content[i].split(" "))]
        return l
```

but when I call the file I get only: [['A', 'B', '1']]

How can I fix it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way you could do it:

abc.txt:

```
A B 1
C D 2
E F 3
```

Code:

```
def f(filename: str) -> list:
    with open(filename,'r') as file:
        return([x.split() for x in file])

print(f("abc.txt"))
```

Result:

```
[['A', 'B', '1'], ['C', 'D', '2'], ['E', 'F', '3']]
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you! Could you just explain to me what happens when we put "for x in file"

Comment: @jin `for x in file` is equal to running through every line in the file, e.g. `for line in file`